# Importar e exportar ficheiro com data - BASE DE DADOS

Tags: vb.net

Boas.
Cenário: "Tenho dois pc's, com o mesmo programa que utiliza uma base de dados. Quero exportar os dados de um pc para por numa pen e importar para o outro pc"

Pergunta: Como faço para seleccionar (enquanto o programa esta a correr) um ficheiro de onde quero que o programa vá buscar os dados. (apenas os dados, não o design de tabelas...)

Tendo em conta que isto é capaz de ser uma pergunta muito grande para as regras deste site, pedia que me dissessem as palavras chaves, de formas/maneiras de fazer o que pretendo, para procurar soluções no google ou ate em livros.

(Podem editar a pergunta se virem que existe uma melhor forma de explicar o que pertendo)

Alguem consegue ajudar?